# Append PHP echo using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have PHP to validate a form, it echos and error message

```
 <?php

if(!$_POST) exit;
error_reporting(0);

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) { 
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));     
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];
$nameerror = 'please enter your name';
if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_name">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><br /><br /><center>Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</center></div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><br /><br /><center>Attention! Please enter a valid phone number.</center></div>';
    exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><br /><br /><center>Attention! Phone number can only contain digits.</center></div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><br /><br /><center>Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</center></div>';
    exit();
}


 else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><br /><br /><center>Attention! Please enter your message.</center></div>';
    exit();
}  


if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

$address = "cedrichugh@yahoo.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name , their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: Website_Contact_Form" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";          
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<center><h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1></center>";
    echo "<center><p>Thank You <strong>$name</strong>, Your Message Has Been Sent. We Will Be In Contact With You Shortly.<br />Med Perfect</p></center>"; 
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
?>
```

But the DIV.error_name displays at the bottom of the page.

How can I append it to the input field so it can be displayed above or below it

```html
<form role="form" id="feedbackForm" method="post" action="index.php?page=contact">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <span class="help-block" style="display:none;">Please enter your name.</span>
            </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Contact Number">
            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid contact number address.</span>
            </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid e-mail address.</span>
            </div>
            
          <div class="form-group">
          <select name="select" class="form-control" id="select">
           <option value="">Please Select Your Interest</option>
           <option value="general_enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
<span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid e-mail address.</span>
          </div>  
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Please enter a message.</span>
            </div>
          
          
          
          <button type="submit" name="submit" id="feedbackSubmit" class="btn44 btn-4 btn-4c icon-mail-send" style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;">Send</button>
          </form>
```

I have tried the following from api.jquery.com(I am a noob)

```
$( "#name" ).append( ".error_name" );
```

Comment: `$( "#name" ).before( '<div class="error_name">You must enter your name.</div>' );` ? http://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: Use jquery's addClass() and removeClass() instead..

Comment: I would like the end result of HTML to look like this:                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">                                                                              <div class="error_name">You must enter your name.</div>                                   Instead of the div appearing before </body> tag

Comment: May I ask why you want to use jQuery for this? It's probebly easier to do with PHP if you're using php to echo it out anyway?

Comment: Because I would like to position that echo underneath the input field instead its being echoed to the bottom of the page

Comment: PHP has no effect on the position of the div. Only css has. I've already got a ready-made example of how exactly to do it with PHP. But I'll need your full html + css code to see what's exactly controlling the position of the error div.

Comment: Do you mind posting the relevant CSS as well? I see classes everywhere, but no CSS. CSS controls the location of your divs. Without it it's impossible to make sure the divs end up where you want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JavaScript function that handles the updating of the DOM with the error message, and the function can be called from anywhere on the page.  You'll be able to trigger the error messages wherever you want, including the HTML file, the JavaScript file, or on the PHP side.

Sample JS function:

```
function displayError(fieldID, errorClass, errorMessage) {
    if ($('#' + fieldID).next('.' + errorClass).length == 0) {
        $('#' + fieldID).after('<div class="' + errorClass + '">' + errorMessage + '</div>');
    }
}
```

To call the JavaScript function (DOM must be ready):

```
displayError('name', 'error_name', 'You must enter your name.');
```

To control the calling of the function from PHP in your server-side validation:

```
if(trim($name) == '') {
    // Call error message function after when DOM is ready
    echo '<script>$(function () { displayError(\'name\', \'error_name\', \'You must enter your name.\'); });</script>';
    exit();
}
```

You could also use the same function when validating on the JavaScript side:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
        event.preventDefault;
        // Validate
        if ($('#name').val() == '') {
            // Name field is empty
            displayError('name', 'error_name', 'You must enter your name.');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/6cLvnk3L/

Comment: Thanks! But only when the submit button is clicked the element <div class="error_name">You must enter your name.</div> is displayed on the page. I tried that but the div still displays at the bottom of the page

Comment: @cedricrademan We probebly need to see your full html and even more importantly your CSS code to see what's messing up the placement of the error div.

Comment: Check the revised fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/gc3rjoge/
I'm doing a very simple validation in JavaScript and appending the error message if the field is empty.

Comment: @BenjaminRay Try sending the Query over and over again in the fiddle! XD. Perhaps check if element already exists or not? :P

Answer (score -1):

How do you add the div to your site?
List of thoughts in order of preference.

- You could leave an empty div (`<div class"error_name"></div>`) where you want the message to appear and add returned text to it (without the surrounding tags).
- Instead of appending a string ".error_name", add the result of  $(".error_name"). So `$( "#name" ).after( $(".error_name") );` if the div is already added to the DOM. `.append()` adds it as a child of input.
- You can also style and position the div with jquery and css without worrying about it's placement in DOM.

Comment: The PHP echos out the div?

Comment: You're doing validation. 
I meant, are you reloading the page with the error message (just move the response up in the code in the correct place). Or more likely you're doing an ajax call, in which case the thoughts listed are valid.

Comment: Since you have it in your DOM, just do $("#name").after($(".error_name")); It will move the element.